# Storyboard collection view refusing to go in front of programmatically created button

Tags: ios, button, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have a storyboard collection view that I hide until a button is pressed. However, there is a programmatically created button that sticks in front of the collection view. The below isn't working. How do I get that programmatically created button behind that storyboard collection view?

```
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:collectionView];
```

Comment: The button needs to be a subview of self.view.  Perhaps you've added the button as a child of the collectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Storyboard make sure the CollectionView be below the button in the list on the left.

If that doesnt work either. Try to insert the view:

```
[self.view insertView:collectionView atIndex:[[self.view subviews]count]+1];
```

OR

```
[self.view insertView:collectionView aboveView:self.button];
```